# Spring-boot default profile for integration tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring-boot utilizes [Spring profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) which allows to have separate config for different environments.
One way I use this feature is to configure the test database to be used by integration tests.
I wonder, however: is it necessary to create my own profile 'test' and explicitly activate this profile in each test file?
Right now, I do it in the following way:

1. Create application-test.properties inside `src/main/resources`
2. Write test-specific config there (just the database name for now)
3. In every test file, include:

   ```
   @ActiveProfiles("test")
   ```

Is there a smarter / more concise way? For instance, a default test profile?

Edit 1: This question pertains to Spring-Boot 1.4.1

Answer (score 146, accepted):

As far as I know there is nothing directly addressing your request - but I can suggest a proposal that could help:

You could use your own test annotation that is a [meta annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-meta-annotations) comprising `@SpringBootTest` and `@ActiveProfiles("test")`. So you still need the dedicated profile but avoid scattering the profile definition across all your test.

This annotation will default to the profile `test` and you can override the profile using the meta annotation.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles
public @interface MyApplicationTest {
  @AliasFor(annotation = ActiveProfiles.class, attribute = "profiles") String[] activeProfiles() default {"test"};
}
```

Comment: How does one use this to declare multiple active profiles to be used by the annotation?

Comment: meta-annotations reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils.html

Comment: @payne `@ActiveProfiles({"dev", "integration"})`

Answer (score 73):

Another way to do this is to define a base (abstract) test class that your actual test classes will extend :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest()
@ActiveProfiles("staging")
public abstract class BaseIntegrationTest {
}
```

Concrete test :

```
public class SampleSearchServiceTest extends BaseIntegrationTest{

    @Inject
    private SampleSearchService service;

    @Test
    public void shouldInjectService(){
        assertThat(this.service).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

This allows you to extract more than just the `@ActiveProfiles` annotation. You could also imagine more specialised base classes for different kinds of integration tests, e.g. data access layer vs service layer, or for functional specialties (common `@Before` or `@After` methods etc).

Comment: can we have an interface instead of a class here?

Answer (score 67):

You could put an application.properties file in your test/resources folder. There you set

```
spring.profiles.active=test
```

This is kind of a default test profile while running tests.

Comment: I use this entry in my testcases if I want to avoid to set @ActiveProfiles("test"). Does it not work for you?

Comment: If I create `src/test/resources/application.properties` file, `src/main/resources/application.properties` content is ignored when running tests.

Comment: @ciastek You can add `application-test.properties` for tests and override only the properties you need.

Comment: @Advicer which doesn't get picked up unless the default properties specify `spring.profiles.active=test` like the answer says.

Comment: @OrangeDog exactly - maybe you can make use of the profile 'default' which is active by default. So you could add such a line in test/resources/application-default.properties (unless of course you already have a src/main/application-default.properties file :-)

Answer (score 50):

There are two approaches.

### Load from `config/`

*(2022 update, tested against Spring Boot 2.6)*

Along with the approach below, you can also add config to `src/test/resources/config/application.yml`

```
src/
├── main/
│   ├── java/
│   │   └── ...
│   └── resources/
│       └── application.yml <- default properties, always loaded
└── test/
    ├── java/
    │   └── ...
    └── resources/
        └── config/
            └── application.yml <- test properties, will override the defaults
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files

> Spring Boot will automatically find and load `application.properties` and `application.yaml` files from the following locations when your application starts:
>
> 1. From the classpath
>
>    1. The classpath root
>    2. The classpath `/config` package
> 2. From the current directory
>
>    1. The current directory
>    2. The `/config` subdirectory in the current directory
>    3. Immediate child directories of the `/config` subdirectory
>
> The list is ordered by precedence (with values from lower items overriding earlier ones). Documents from the loaded files are added as `PropertySources` to the Spring `Environment`.

#### Manual import using `spring.config.import`

*(original answer from 2021, tested against Spring Boot 2.4)*

One solution is to have 3 properties files and to import

- `src/main/resources/application.yml` - contains the application's default props
- `src/test/resources/application.yml` - sets the profile to 'test', and imports properties from 'main'
- `src/test/resources/application-test.yml` - contains test-specific profiles, which will override 'main'

Here is the content of `src/test/resources/application.yml`:

```yaml
# for testing, set default profile to 'test'
spring.profiles.active: "test"
# and import the 'main' properties
spring.config.import: file:src/main/resources/application.yml
```

For example, if `src/main/resources/application.yml` has the content

```yaml
ip-address: "10.7.0.1"
username: admin
```

and `src/test/resources/application-test.yml` has

```yaml
ip-address: "999.999.999.999"
run-integration-test: true
```

Then (assuming there are no other profiles)...

when running tests,

```
profiles=test
--
ip-address=999.999.999.999
username=admin
run-integration-test=true
```

and when running the application normally

```
profiles=none
--
ip-address=10.7.0.1
username=admin
run-integration-test <undefined>
```

---

Note: if `src/main/resources/application.yml` contains `spring.profiles.active: "dev"`, then this won't be overwritten by `src/test/resources/application-test.yml`

Comment: It's strange that without the `src/test/resources/application.yml` file, `environment.getActiveProfiles()` will still return the correct test profile but if I get the active profile via `@Value("${spring.profiles.active:}")` annotation, it will be null.

Comment: By following your example, in my `src/test/resources/application-test.properties`, I put `spring.config.import:file:src/main/resources/application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties`. It allows me to run my test suite with the active profile. Thank you !

Answer (score 24):

A delarative way to do that (In fact, a minor tweek to @Compito's original answer):

1. Set `spring.profiles.active=test` in `test/resources/application-default.properties`.
2. Add `test/resources/application-test.properties` for tests and override only the properties you need.

Comment: Does it mean the default `application.properties` in the classpath gets parsed too, then the `test/resources/application-default.properties` and then, because the profile "test" is detected, the `test/resources/application-test.properties` gets parsed? Otherwise it would not solve @ciastek's issue as commented under [@Compito's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39697026/2237467).

Comment: I am getting this error with Spring Boot 2.4.5: "Property 'spring.profiles.active' imported from location 'class path resource [application-default.yml]' is invalid in a profile specific resource [origin: class path resource [application-default.yml]"

Comment: this doesn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 17):

You can put your test specific properties into `src/test/resources/config/application.properties`.

The properties defined in this file will override those defined in `src/main/resources/application.properties` during testing.

For more information on why this works have a look at [Spring Boots docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files).

Comment: Many good ideas here useful for many cases. IMHO @Matze answer is the most concise and straightforward answer for this question, No Profiles Needed, No Modifying Test Code Needed...  Also logging is cleaner (so confusing in my case that Spring logs Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL93Dialect when my test is, thankfully, using the test H2 database instead).

Comment: Wow, I did not expect to find THE right answer so deep in the list.

Answer (score 11):

If you use maven, you can add this in pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Dspring.profiles.active=test ${argLine}</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
```

Then, maven should run your integration tests (*IT.java) using this arugument, and also IntelliJ will start with this profile activated - so you can then specify all properties inside

```
application-test.yml
```

and you should not need "-default" properties.

**UPDATE**

added `${argLine}` for this to work together with other plugins (e.g. jacoco)

Comment: Worked for me, but had to add configurations to surefire plugin too along with failsafe.

Answer (score 8):

To activate "test" profile write in your build.gradle:

```
    test.doFirst {
        systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', 'test'
        activeProfiles = 'test'
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case I have different application.properties depending on the environment, something like:

```
application.properties (base file)
application-dev.properties
application-qa.properties
application-prod.properties
```

and application.properties contains a property spring.profiles.active to pick the proper file.

For my integration tests, I created a new `application-test.properties` file inside `test/resources` and with the `@TestPropertySource({ "/application-test.properties" })` annotation this is the file who is in charge of picking the application.properties I want depending on my needs for those tests

Comment: You should use `@ActiveProfiles`, not `@TestPropertySource`.

Comment: I think it doesn't mind for using @TestPropertiesSource. It's also the way to load the configuration between the profile test configuration.

Answer (score 4):

Another programatically way to do that:

```
  import static org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.DEFAULT_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAME;

  @BeforeClass
  public static void setupTest() {
    System.setProperty(DEFAULT_PROFILES_PROPERTY_NAME, "test");
  }
```

It works great.

Answer (score 3):

I've usually done a base class for all integration tests with common code and annotations. Do not forget make it `abstract` in order not to instatiate. E.g:

```
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public abstract class AbstractControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    protected ResultActions perform(MockHttpServletRequestBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        return mockMvc.perform(builder);
    }
}

// All annotations are inherited
class AccountControllerTest extends AbstractControllerTest {
....
```

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to set/use default profile at the time of making build through maven then, pass the argument 
`-Dspring.profiles.active=test`
Just like

> mvn clean install -Dspring.profiles.active=dev

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I have found is the last suggestion here: https://inspeerity.com/blog/setting-default-spring-profile-for-tests-with-override-option/
The author also desribes the problem very clearly and discusses the downside of every other approach I can think of.

Create a file `application-default.properties` in your test resources, containing a single line:

```
spring.profiles.active=test
```

This takes advantage of the fact that Spring automatically enables a "default" profile if no other profiles were explicitly set. Now, your `application-test.properties` file will be used by default, for all tests.

Comment: Actually, looks like this is no longer supported as of Spring Boot 2.4... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67935961/property-spring-profiles-active-imported-from-location-class-path-resource-a

Answer (score 0):

Add `spring.profiles.active=tests` in your application.properties file, you can add multiple properties file in your spring boot application like  `application-stage.properties`, `application-prod.properties`, etc. And you can specify in your application.properties file while file to refer by adding `spring.profiles.active=stage` or `spring.profiles.active=prod`

you can also pass the profile at the time running the spring boot application by providing the command:

`java -jar`**`-Dspring.profiles.active=local`**`build/libs/turtle-rnr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

According to the profile name the properties file is picked up, in the above case passing profile `local` consider the `application-local.properties` file