# Profile Specific application.properties Not Applied During Unit Test

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm writing integration tests, and I'd like to use Spring profiles to configure properties for each environment. However I'm finding profile specific application properties (e.g. *application-dev.yml*, *application-prod.yml*) in my *src/test/resources* directory aren't activated the same way they are in *src/main/resources*. It appears running tests with `-Dspring.profiles.active=prod` has no effect. Is it possible to activate a profile from the command line for tests?

Note: `@ActiveProfiles` isn't sufficient because I want to run the same tests against multiple environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [similar issue reported in GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/592) and the [solution](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/592#issuecomment-38901467) was applicable to my problem. The JVM system property `spring.profiles.active` wasn't getting picked-up in Gradle. So I modified my task as follows

```
integrationTest {
    systemProperties = System.properties
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have copied the file names from your workspace but 'applicaiton-prod.yml' has a typo in it. That could be the reason.

Comment: Thanks, but the file in my project was spelt correctly.

Comment: cant do much without seeing the project setup. maybe answers from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39690094 will help.