# Excluding Configuration in Spring boot test

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing

I have the following setup in a maven project.
Configuration class for the productive code:

```
package com.example;
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public A beanA() {
      return new A();
    }
    ...
}
```

Then I have one test, that has an internal `Configuration`:

```
package com.example;
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyConfiguration.class, SpringConfigurationTest.MyTestConfiguration.class})
public class SpringConfigurationTest {
    @TestConfiguration
    static class MyTestConfiguration {
        @Bean
        @Primary
        public A beanA() {
          return mock(A.class);
        }    
    }
}
```

The tests in this class work fine. Then I do have another Test class in sub package:

```
package com.example.sub;
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyConfiguration.class, AnotherSpringConfigurationTest.MyTestConfiguration.class})
public class AnotherSpringConfigurationTest {
    @TestConfiguration
    static class MyTestConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public B beanB() {
          return new B()
        }    
    }
}
```

When running tests in this class the test configuration from `SpringConfigurationTest.MyTestConfiguration` is also included. My guess the reason for this is the inclusion of `MyConfiguration` which lies in the root directory. The effect is that in `AnotherSpringConfigurationTest` the bean `A` is mocked instead of a real instance.

How can I avoid that configuration classes inside other tests are 'leaked' into other tests?

I have seen [Spring-boot default profile for integration tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39690094/spring-boot-default-profile-for-integration-tests) which uses Spring profiles in Spring Boot 1.4.1, while I am using Spring Boot 2.0.1. Though I am sure it could be done.

Another approach I could think of would be to use component scanning to pick up the contexts and exclude all those that I do not want, but that is a bit cumbersome, as I would much prefer an approach where I define what I want to use instead of what should not be used.

Is there an easy and elegant solution with Spring Boot 2 to avoid conflicting context configurations?

Comment: what tells you that `SpringConfigurationTest.MyTestConfiguration` is also included ? Any errors ?

Comment: Log output states that bean `A` is overridden based on `SpringConfigurationTest.MyTestConfiguration` and when debugging I can see that it is a mock instead of the real thing.

Comment: How do you retrieve Beans in your test ? With `@Autowired` ? Right now, I see 2 Beans `A` and you should have had a `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException`. So how do you do ?

Comment: This example is maybe oversimplified, so in these occasions, I add the @Primary as suggested in your answer. However in `AnotherSpringConfigurationTest`, I would expect to have only one bean definition present and that being the one from `MyConfiguration`

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't like the idea of putting a config class in another class. I don't know if that is frenquently made, I'm kinda new to Spring. But here is what I would do :

First config file :

```
@Configuration
@Import(MyConfiguration.class)
public class MyTestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Primary // added to let know on @Autowired to use this one instead of the one in first MyConfiguration.class
    public A beanA() {
      return mock(A.class);
    }    
}
```

Second config file :

```
@Configuration
@Import(MyConfiguration.class)
public class MyOtherTestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public B beanB() {
      return new B()
    }    
}
```

I'm not familiar with `@TestConfiguration`. That's why i'm using `@Configuration`.

First test class :

```
package com.example;
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyTestConfiguration.class)
public class SpringConfigurationTest {

}
```

Second test class :

```
package com.example.sub;
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyOtherTestConfiguration.class)
public class AnotherSpringConfigurationTest {

}
```

Comment: I had the configurations in a separate file, but that did not change a thing.

Comment: It's not that it will not work, I just don't like the concept.

Comment: Tried your approach with having one configuration and bringing in the others with `@Import`. Did not work, I assume because Spring boot just does not work that way, but takes the configuration as root to scan for further beans, which configurations are one kind of.

Comment: I tried the setup you provided and it worked with no problem. So I don't think the problem is on your test setup.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. The real bean is always loaded and it says "There is already...". I think the best way is still using @Profile.