# I am upgrading to spring boot 2.5.12, and am getting this error below

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

Here is the pom file, I read somewhere it might be a spring-coud dependency issue? I can also see that is saying in the error output it may be related to spring core.

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

This is the error I am getting when trying to run the application. ( no class definition found )

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2309) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467) ~[spring-core-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 1):

After `</dependencies>`, add Spring cloud in dependency management

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Edit:
You can use

```
<spring-cloud.version>2020.0.5</spring-cloud.version>
```

as per https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud

Comment: Thank you this worked! just a side note if anyone faces an issue with the application-test properties look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67935961/property-spring-profiles-active-imported-from-location-class-path-resource-a

Comment: I'm getting the exact same error and after adding the dependency still it's failing with the same error.